# inserting enum types to aurora postgres using boto3

Tags: postgresql, boto3, amazon-aurora

I have a schema which has a string and and enum that I am trying to write to using boto3.  I create a sql, specify parameters and run execute_statement. Easy enough for strings and dates:

```
    sql = """
          insert into scrape_results(lname,fname, dob) values (:lname, :fname, :dob)
          """              
    param1 = {'name':'lname', 'value':{'stringValue': 'xx'}}
    param3 = {'name':'dob', 'typeHint': 'DATE', 'value':{'stringValue': '1970-01-01'}}
    param_set = [param1, param2]     
    response = rds_data.execute_statement(
        resourceArn = cluster_arn, 
        secretArn = secret_arn, 
        database = 'db', 
        sql = sql,
        parameters = param_set)
```

The 3rd field I have is an enum. I do not follow how to insert an enum. There is no typeHint for enum, and boto does not accept a stringValue. I tried this: (court_type is the enum)

```
param3 = {'name':'court',  'value':{'stringValue': 'court'}}
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: 
ERROR: operator does not exist: court_type = character varying

Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
You might need to add explicit type casts
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Hard to find any documentation on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to this to get around it:

```
sql_statement = f"""
    INSERT INTO
        s_info(jurisdiction, court, us_state)
    VALUES(
        '{req.jurisdiction}',
        '{req.court_type}', #enum
        '{req.state}'
    )
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
"""

rds_data = boto3.client('rds-data', region_name='xxx')
try:
    response = rds_data.execute_statement(
        resourceArn=CLUSTER_ARN,
        secretArn=SECRET_ARN,
        database=DATABASE,
        sql=sql_statement
        )
except ClientError as exc:
    #print(f"failed to execute {sql_statement} because {exc}")
    raise
```

Comment: what happens if i set my state or jurisdiction to something like `'); drop table users;` tho?

pls try my answer and if it works go back to your parameters, they're a lot safer when dealing with user input. using parameters gives you a shape that naturally protects you from sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

given your enum is named court_type you can set values in your statement using a string parameter like this `... values(:jurisdiction, cast(:court_type as court_type), :state) ...`. cast will turn a string from aws's data api into a court_type type.